# Unable to pull database from realtime database of Google in next js app

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, next.js

Currently I am not able to pull the database from Google Realtime Database and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Below is the code that is in my Categories page.

```js
import CategoryHeader from '../../components/CategoryHeader';
import database from '../../DataManagement/data/data.json';
import Product from './product';

import { app } from '../../firebase/firebase';

export default function Categories({ data }) {
    // console.log(data)

    const productData = database

    return ( 
        <section>
            <CategoryHeader header="All Products"/>
            <div className="catergory">
                <ul>
            {
                productData.map((data) => {
                    return <li key={data.id}><Product 
                         
                        productName={data.name} 
                        productDescription={data.description} 
                        productImage={data.image.desktop}/>
                        </li>
                })
            }
            </ul>
        </div>
        </section>
    )
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
    const res = await fetch('https://audiophile-a8abd-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com');
    const data = res.json();

    return {
        props: {
            data,
        }
    }
}
```

I have the basic setup from Firebase in a firebase configuration below.

```js
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyDrrHKenRbeiyfUO58v88TSJEdtWumWZjk",
  authDomain: "audiophile-a8abd.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://audiophile-a8abd-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "audiophile-a8abd",
  storageBucket: "audiophile-a8abd.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "193961133135",
  appId: "1:193961133135:web:9c9e8731fc281a68eb563a",
  measurementId: "G-V2C17TC2ZN"
};

// Initialize Firebase
export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
// const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
```

The error I continue to get is "SerializableError: Error serializing `.data` returned from `getStaticProps` in "/categories"."

Any ideas how to get the live data?

Comment: Note that the database import is the working option of the json file that I am using. I would like to NOT use this option since I'll be using this to create different category pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work:

```
const res = await fetch('https://audiophile-a8abd-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com');
const data = res.json();
```

If you open that URL in your browser, you have to sign in and then get taken to the Firebase console for the project. And `fetch` is not equipped to handle that, nor is it what you actually want.

If you want to get the JSON from your database, you're looking to use the Firebase [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start) and you need to ensure the path of the URL ends with `.json`. So:

```
const res = await fetch('https://audiophile-a8abd-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/.json');
const data = res.json();
```

Comment: Thank you Frank! I completely missed it but now I have it working with an adjustment in the code.

export async function getStaticProps() {
    let data;
    try {
        const res = await fetch('https://audiophile-a8abd-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/data.json');
        data = await res.json();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }

    return {
        props: {
            data,
        }
    }
}